# passing a variable from one class to another, without altering method names

Tags: java

I have a class Course that needs to pass a JUnit case in a test class, therefore the method name getNumberStudents needs to remain the same.

```
public class Course {

private Students students = null;

public Course(Students students, Grades grades) {
    this.students = students;
}
public int getNumberStudents() {
    int numberStudents = 0;     
    numberstudents = students.getNumberStudents();      
    return numberStudents;
}
```

However, I need to access the data using another class, 'Students'. Due to how the test class is setup, I can't modify the method signature in this class either. Can someone please tell me how I can pass the result I am printing out in the Students class to the Course class?

```
public class Students {

public Students(String studentsDb) {
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(studentsDb));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        int numberStudents = 0;

        // Get first sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            if (row.getRowNum() == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            numberStudents = numberStudents + 1;
        }
        System.out.println(numberStudents);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or, is there a simpler way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing `students.getNumberStudents();` when `students` is of type `Students` but your `Students` class doesn't have a `getNumberStudents()` method?

Or is there more to the class?

Comment: That's the stumbling block i'm running into. Eclipse tells me to create a `getNumberStudents()` method in the Students class, but I can't rename `public Students(String studentsDb)` due to how it is accessing the database. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Why can't you add an instance variable `numstudents` into the students class and have your constructor set that equal to the number it gets from the database?

Comment: You shouldn't alter the existing method (the constructor), you just need to add a second method to your class alongside it.

Comment: Even better. But won't that be a lot of rewritten code rather than changing one line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do something like:

```
public Class Students {
    private int numStudents;

    public Students(String studentsDb) {
        //Keep everything the same

        //add this line under the print statement:
        this.numStudents = numberStudents;
    }

    public int getNumberStudents() {
        return numStudents;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Course` class you can now do `students.getNumberStudents();`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! I spent too many hours trying to properly pass a variable to that second method; and then in turn to the other class. Thank you much guys...

Comment: @yodish no problem! I just have a question. If your `Students` class has no other methods other than the constructor and the method I provided, why don't you just make the students constructor a method of `Course`, and then have `private int numStudents` be a instance variable of course?

Comment: Something to consider, but the answer would be: because i'm coding out of my rear-end. Your suggestion is probably the correct way. If I have time for cleanup, I may look into that. Thanks again...